User cannot interact with programmatically opened Word Document until they hit Ctrl+Home. Ribbon and Scroll bars remain accessible
Some of our users have recently started complaining that when they open Word documents through our application they cannot interact with them. When they try to scroll the document up and down using the vertical scrollbar the scrollbar moves just fine, but the document doesn't move at all. The Ribbon Bar is fully accessible. When the user clicks anywhere in the document, "nothing happens".
But in fact there is nothing wrong with the document. The moment you hit the keyboard to type in any letter, the letter appears, and from that moment on the document behaves normally. If you hit Ctrl+Home the cursor starts blinking at the start of the document and it starts behaving normally. You can even click buttons in the Ribbon Bar and many of the actions will result in the document becoming accessible again. Even simple actions like zooming in or out of the document will resolve the problem.
So to me it looks like when the document opens the "focus" goes somewhere it shouldn't, and any of these actions will bring it back to a more sensible point in the document after which the user can interact with it again.
After some investigation I discovered that the offending documents appear to share one feature: they have Footnotes in them.
The code we use to open the document seems quite straightforward:
We create a Word.Application object and we use its Open method to open the document (VB Code)
    oDoc = oWApp.Documents.Open(<filepath here>)

We add some code to ensure Word is visible to the user (if necessary) or to Activate the application
oWapp.Visible = True
oWApp.Activate()

We avoid strange panel settings
If oWapp.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSpecialPane.wdPaneNone Then
    If oWapp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdViewType.wdWebView Then
        oWapp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView
    End If
Else
    If oWapp.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdViewType.wdWebView Then
        oWapp.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView
    End If
End If

And finally we activate the document
oWapp.ActiveDocument.Activate()

This has always worked fine but one thing we noticed is that the people who started complaining are on Office Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160 64-bit - I am too and I can reproduce the problem on my own PC
When I do this with a document without Footnotes in it, everything behaves as it always has. The document opens and is activated, and the user can scroll and click into the document body immediately. So far it looks like this only affects documents with footnotes in them.
At the moment I implemented one minor change that appears to avoid the problem... but it's ugly. I don't like having to rely on sleeping a Thread for something to work, so I coded it to only do this when there are actually some Foot- or Endnotes in the document. We are not in a position to test this on a customer machine yet. Instead of simply Activating the Active Document, we now add code to check for Foot- or Endnotes and we sleep the thread for a second. After Activating the document we programmatically emulate the user hitting Ctrl+Home. I cannot begin to express how much I hate this cludge.
Try
    Dim bSleptAlready As Boolean = False
    If DirectCast(oWapp.ActiveDocument, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document).Footnotes IsNot Nothing Then
        If DirectCast(oWapp.ActiveDocument, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document).Footnotes.Count > 0 Then
            bSleptAlready = True
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End If
    End If
    If Not bSleptAlready Then
        If DirectCast(oWapp.ActiveDocument, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document).Endnotes IsNot Nothing Then
            If DirectCast(oWapp.ActiveDocument, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document).Endnotes.Count > 0 Then
                bSleptAlready = True
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    oWapp.ActiveDocument.Activate()
    If bSleptAlready Then
        DirectCast(oWapp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application).Selection.HomeKey(Unit:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory)
        DirectCast(oWapp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application).ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 0
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try

I'd be looking for answers to any of these questions:

Is anybody aware of this having been reported as an issue with a recent update to Microsoft Word? (I have asked this of Microsoft, also, and if they give me an answer I will post it here)
If anyone has come across this before, is there a way to programmatically detect the presence of footnotes and to perform any programmatical actions to avoid this problem? We have told people "just hit Ctrl+Home" but apparently even an instruction that simple is beyond some.


Try "sending keystrokes" to MS Word. You may need some extra steps to "focus" the target window (as explained in the link) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

It seems to me that the window is actually already in focus. When you hit the "x" key on your keyboard, an "x" appears in the document and suddenly it behaves the way it should. When I tried the HomeKey code before without the 1 second sleep beforehand it wasn't working.

While I am still very unhappy that this issue raised its ugly head, I was able to find the code in our Addin that appeared to be causing the problem.
Without going into detail ...
We use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in order to open Word documents stored in our application's "document storage". We also have a Word Addin that tracks when users save documents they are working on so that if they save "one of our documents", it gets saved back to our "document storage"
To do this, our main application accesses the Addin object after it gets a handle on the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application in order to set Custom Properties in the Word.Documents it opens. These custom properties are what allows our Addin to distinguish between "local" documents that are none of our business and "our" documents that need to be saved back to our "document storage".
This is where the problem seems to be caused: We set Custom Properties, then we Save the document and reset its Saved property back to what it was before we did all this. And in the process, even though we do not explicitly tell Word through anything we do through Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to change the Cursor location or focus in the document, it somehow gets lost.
Ideally this is an issue that Microsoft should fix, but if we wait for them to do something we'll be losing customers while we're waiting.
The solution seems to be fairly straightforward. In our addin I found the code where we set the user properties and save them back to the document, and after that we simply do:
<wordapplication>.Selection.HomeKey(wdUnits)
<wordapplication>.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 0

And the problem has "gone away"
This is similar to the "cludge" I described in my original question except there we were doing it from the calling application. Now we're doing it within the Addin.
